# Excluding specific elements when styling

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am adding custom CSS to my Wordpress theme to add a border to all images - however I need to figure out how to exclude the logo images in the header and the footer so that they don't have a border around them. Any ideas?

I've tried using the :not command in CSS, however I cannot figure out how to add a class to my header logo and my footer logo. 
Here's the simple code I am adding to style the images:

```
img { border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 4px; }
```

The hard part is now figuring out how to stop that CSS from putting a border around the images in the header and the footer.
Here's the page where I am trying to do this: 
http://disaprimary.co.za/silikamva/about/staff-and-teachers/

Comment: Could use the [:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo-class to exclude images with a special class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to add a class to the images in footer and header like this:

```
<img src="" class= "noborder">
```

And in your CSS:

```
img:not(.noborder){
  border-radius: 4px; border: 1px solid #dddddd; padding: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add the below given css:

```
a.brand img {
    border: none;
}

div#media_image-4 a img {
    border: none;
}
```

It will exclude the border of header and footer logo images.